# OSError: libtaos.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tdengine

I have this error exception when installing TDengine. Have any of you encountered it before?

I tried to install the application, but he raised this exception: OSError: libtaos.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't installed TDengine client installation package or TDengine server installation package, you should install either client or server first.

If you have already installed one of them, you should check it be linked in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib path. Manually link might help to solve your problem.